# Migrating Bugzilla - Can't find data directory

Tags: linux, migration, bugzilla

I have been tasked with migrating Bugzilla to a new server.  So far I have been able to get the environment set up properly following this guide https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Move_Installation, but I am unable to find the **data** directory I need to copy to the new install location (Step #4)

This seems pretty straightforward but I haven't been able to find it anywhere in the old Bugzilla directory, or any other resources about this.  Both servers (old and new) are running Linux.  I am upgrading from Bugzilla 4.0.2 to 4.2.4

Any ideas of what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data directory is directly off the top-level Bugzilla directory. It must exist if your Bugzilla is working, because the file "data/params" contains all of the parameters defining how Bugzilla works. If it's not present, any attempt to access a Bugzilla page will give this error:

```
The ./data/params file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. 
at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 317.
```

The only possible reason it might not exist is that your Bugzilla has never been used, and you've never even run checksetup.pl - but if that's so, why are you "moving" rather than doing a new install?

Gerv

Comment: You're right.  I was referencing an old (broken) install on Bugzilla.  Once I found the right instal location the data folder was in the root Bugzilla directory and I was able to transfer the existing data to a fresh install.